# introduzir o nome completo e fazer print do o ultimo nome com a virgula ao lado e por fim os nomes ex: José Barroso Santos ficar Santos, José Barroso

Tags: python

Eu consegui fazer o código mas com a virgula a separar todos os nomes

```
nome_completo = input("Insira o seu nome: ")

apelido=nome_completo.split()

nome=' , '.join(apelido[i] for i in range(-1, len(apelido) - 1))

print(nome)
```

Answer (score -2):

Para isso utilize lista e slice/fatia de uma lista.
Vamos supor que o nome completo seja **José Santos Barroso**, então:

`nome="José Santos Barroso"`

em seguida, você pode criar uma lista baseado no nome, sendo cada nome/sobrenome/palavra um item da lista, utilizando a função `split` como você fez, ficando:

`apelido=['José', 'Santos', 'Barroso']`

Agora, através de índice / fatia, é possível pegar um ou mais elementos da lista para outra variável tipo string (um único elemento), ou outra lista (mais de um elemento).
Para pegar o último elemento de uma lista, pode-se utilizar um índice negativo, como:

`ultimo_nome = apelido[-1]`

e também podemos pegar o restante do nome, sendo do primeiro elemento até o penúltimo elemento da lista (pois o último elemento é o "sobrenome"), ficando:

`resto = apelido[0:-1]`

agora, só concatenar a variável `resto` para uma string separada por espaço:

`' '.join(resto)`

segue o código completo:

```
nome_completo = input("Insira o seu nome: ")
apelido = nome_completo.split()

ultimo_nome = apelido[-1]
resto = apelido[0:-1]

print('{}, {}'.format(ultimo_nome, ' '.join(resto)))
```